# Is correct to save in the environment variables of angular a variable that determines if the current page is loading?

Tags: angular, http, asynchronous

I'm trying to make a spinner appear whenever i make an http request on angular. My idea was saving a variable called "loading" in `environment.ts` and update it to true or false using a service. If the variable is true the loading spinner styles change so it becomes visible, and if it's false you can deduce what happens. I'm a neewbie with angular so i don't really know if this is the optimum approach.

My question is the following, is correct to develop this feature this way? Or developing it this way is a bad angular practice?

Answer (score 2):

If by "environment variable", you mean, `environment.ts` then no. You should consider this as readonly.

If you want to add some behavior on every request, you should consider using an [HttpInterceptor](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpInterceptor), they are intended for this purpose.

Also, if you want to share context throughout the application, you can create a dedicated service that is `{providedIn: 'root'}` (which is the default behavior when you create a service via `ng generate service`). This way, every component that injects the service will share the same and only instance of the service.

In my applications, I usually create a spinner in a dedicated service and I call it manually when needed. I have too much requests so it might not be a good idea to display it on *every* request.

Example :

```js
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class MyLoaderService {

  /**
   * a counter is needed for this scenario :
   * - request 1 is sent : show the loader
   * - request 2 is sent : still show the same loader. Do not show another one
   * - response 1 is received : loader must still be shown because there is still another request
   * - response 2 is received : hide the loader
   */
  count = 0;

  private dialog: MatDialogRef<MyLoaderComponent>;

  constructor(private matDialog: MatDialog) {}

  show() {
    if (this.count === 0) {
      this.dialog = this.matDialog.open(MyLoaderComponent, {
        panelClass: 'loader-modalbox',
        backdropClass: 'loader-backdrop',
        disableClose: true ,
        autoFocus: true,
      });
    }
    this.count++;
  }

  hide() {
    this.count--;
    if (this.count < 0) {
      if (isDevMode()) {
        console.trace("loader count not suppose to go under 0 !");
      }
      this.count = 0;
    }

    if (this.count === 0) {
      this.dialog.close();
    }
  }
}
```

Usage :

```js
this.loaderService.show();
this.backendService.foo()
.pipe(finalize(() => this.loaderService.hide()))
.subscribe([...])
```